# Script won't run with sudo, but will without

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and was working on a script when I found this issue: Any script (even just `echo test`) run by the file does not work and just shows a green cursor. When I hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel it, it asks for my account password and if I type it in it just accepts it and does nothing.

Green cursor:
[image: Green cursor]

Account password, then nothing:
[image: Account password, then nothing]

Comment: What is in the contents of test.sh?

Comment: are you able to `sudo -i` and then run the script?

Comment: I've tried sudo -i and that doesn't seem to work

The file is litterally just
 ```#!/bin/bash```
echo test

Comment: Have you tried `#!/bin/bash`  `sudo echo test`? It should ask for password and continue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I gave that a go and I'm getting the same result..

Comment: What is the output of `type -a sudo`? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user running the script a sudoer? 
check the permissions on the script,make sure u execute chmod +x test.sh
make sure you start the script by this #!/bin/bash 
try to run the script by this command sudo /bin/bash test.sh

Comment: Tried all of that with no success, I am a sudoer on the system and sudo does work for everything else other than running scripts.. I've tried the shebang and trying to make it executable and the other things you mentioned with no success

Comment: sudo /bin/bash -v test.sh what does this print on screen?

Comment: It doesn't print anything, It's just the same thing..

Comment: sudo visudo
Add this in the file: jamo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to restart the sshd service, I guess it was just a bug with OpenSSH?

Comment: This solution alone doesn't make much sense; possibly a red herring. It certainly doesn't shed any light on the culprit. I think there must have been something else, e.g. the shell and terminal settings reloaded anew after you logged in again (you did log in again, didn't you?) and whatever weird settings had been responsible, they were no more. It's only a speculation though (but so is "bug with OpenSSH").